# Lock a table with ACCESS EXCLUSIVE using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, locking, psycopg2

I am trying to explicitly lock a table using `psycopg2` with Django & Heroku, so it is not accessed by any other server/worker in the meantime.

I read that `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` does exactly what I need. However, I have only found [explanations about when it is automatically called (with `DROP TABLE`, `VACUUM FULL`, etc.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html); but I don't know how I can call it explicitly, to lock the table at my will.

I tried the following:

```
 with SQL().con2db() as conn:

   cur = conn.cursor()

    lock_query = 'ACCESS EXCLUSIVE {tbl_name}'.format(tbl_name=tbl_name)
    cur.execute(lock_query, )

    #do whatever

    cur.close()
```

But I get an error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "ACCESS"
LINE 1: ACCESS EXCLUSIVE table_name
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lock a table explicitly, use the SQL statement [`LOCK`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html).

Since locks are only held until the end of a database transaction, you have to explicitly start and end a transaction.

Since that affects concurrency considerably, you should consider if there is not a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! I think in psycopg2 the transactions are explicitly started and ended with `cur.exectue()` and `cur.close()`, is that correct?

Comment: I don't know, maybe [this page](https://bbengfort.github.io/observations/2017/12/06/psycopg2-transactions.html) has some information.

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigation, I found [this post](https://nordeus.com/blog/engineering/postgresql-locking-revealed/) that speaks about advisory locks:

> ### Advisory Locks
>
> Postgres provides a means for creating locks that have
>   application-defined meanings. These are called advisory locks, because
>   the system does not enforce their use — it is up to the application to
>   use them correctly.
>
> There are two ways to acquire an advisory lock in Postgres: at session
>   level or at transaction level. Once acquired at session level, an
>   advisory lock is held until explicitly released or the session ends.
>   Unlike standard lock requests, session-level advisory lock requests do
>   not honor transaction semantics: a lock acquired during a transaction
>   that is later rolled back will still be held following the rollback,
>   and likewise an unlock is effective even if the calling transaction
>   fails later. A lock can be acquired multiple times by its owning
>   process; for each completed lock request there must be a corresponding
>   unlock request before the lock is actually released. Transaction-level
>   lock requests, on the other hand, behave more like regular lock
>   requests: they are automatically released at the end of the
>   transaction, and there is no explicit unlock operation. This behavior
>   is often more convenient than the session-level behavior for
>   short-term usage of an advisory lock. Session-level and
>   transaction-level lock requests for the same advisory lock identifier
>   will block each other in the expected way. If a session already holds
>   a given advisory lock, additional requests by it will always succeed,
>   even if other sessions are awaiting the lock; this statement is true
>   regardless of whether the existing lock hold and new request are at
>   session level or transaction level. Complete list of functions for
>   manipulating advisory locks can be found in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS).
>
> ...
>
> ```
> -- Transaction 1
> BEGIN;
>
> SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(1);
> -- Some work here
> ```

I am not sure how this exactly works, as I am not specifying the table I want to block, but it seems to do the job.

```
with SQL().con2db() as conn:

    cur = conn.cursor()

    lock_query = 'SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(1);'
    cur.execute(lock_query, )

    #do whatever

    cur.close()
```

Any further explanations to understand it better or alternative approaches are more than welcome.